# Redirecting AWK output back to the input file

Tags: awk

Consider the bash command, where file is a file with a single nonempty line.

```
awk '{print "stuff"}' file >> file
```

It seems like this should do the following: awk reads a line of file, writes "stuff" to it, and then proceeds to the next line, at which point, it should write stuff to file again, and so on to infinity. But, instead, it just terminates after writing once. Why is this? Is this a property of the file system, unix piping or awk?

Comment: Excellent question! My guess would be that this has to do with the redirection behaviour: AWK reads the first line, tries reading the second line while printing the first line, fails, so only the first line gets appended. However I'm not sure that the official documentation contains enough detail to answer this since it depends on many things (buffering, order of evaluation, concurrency, ...)

Comment: This is a shell question, it has nothing to do with awk (i.e. it would have the same behavior no matter what command you were using instead of awk), so tag your question with bash and shell to get the shell gurus looking at it and so get the exact answer to "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, you just need a bigger file:

```
$ echo foo > foo
$ awk '{print $1}' foo >> foo
$ wc -l foo
2 foo
```

But:

```
$ for i in {1..4096} ; do echo $i ; done >> foo
$ awk '{print $1}' foo >> foo
^C
$ wc -l foo
19429617 foo
```

Using GNU awk in this example. I assume it (GNU awk) opens the file and reads one full block of data, not just one record. If there is less than or equal to the size of one block amount of data, it closes the file from reading. If there is more, it keeps the file open for reading until EOF and keeps appending to the end of it.

Comment: Hi @jmaes, in the second example, why there are more than 4096*2=8192 lines in foo after `awk` executed?

Comment: Awk keeps adding more records to the end of the file while reading them later.

Comment: Actually I tried `for i in {1..10} ; do echo $i ; done >> bar`, and then `awk '{print $1}' bar >> bar ; wc -l bar`. Every time I can get double amount of lines compared with last time.

Comment: That is correct (under my assumption above). But once the file has more than one fs block of data in it (for example my block size is 4096 bytes) awk won't close the file from reading after reading the first block.

Comment: I tried 1000 lines is fine to process, but 2000 would get stuck. Seems like `awk` stuck into the infinite loop. Interesting.

Comment: Funny. The threshold is 4100 bytes. 4101 bytes is the first file size for awk to loop forever. That's 1041 records with my `for` loop and the first record is 11 or 111 for my block size of 4096.

Comment: I'd say, let others read this and comment (hey @EdMorton, got any insight to this?). I need to have breakfast right now.

Comment: Yes. Do **not** rely on writing to the input file working! You're relying on buffering and the order the shell opens the file and all sorts of things that can produce nasal demons instead of doing what you want. Just don't do it, do `awk '{print "stuff"}' file > tmp && cat tmp >> file && rm tmp` instead.